# Read array in case of catch exception

Tags: php, arrays, try-catch

In case of catch (Exception $e) , the following code fails at the line $lat = $track[0]. How to fix it?

```
$track = getPositionalTrack();
$lat = $track[0];
$lon = $track[1];

function getPositionalTrack()
{
    $track = array();
    $url = "https://...";
    try
    {
        $result = file_get_contents($url);
        $obj = json_decode($result, true);
        $lat =  $obj["lat"];
        $lon = $obj["lon"];
        $track[0] = $lat;
        $track[1] = $lon;
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        die('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
    return $track;
}
```

Comment: What does "fail" mean? What is the output? What is the error? Also, none of the code in the `try` block will ever throw any exception.

Comment: Did you tried `var_dump($obj);` in `try {}` block?

Comment: Also, if there is error in `json_decode()` you can check it with `json_last_error()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: Also, I'd not use an exception in this code: A normal error checking and handling would be a better design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like deceze noted neither `file_get_contents` nor `json_decode` will throw an exception.
So you have to rewrite the function in a defensive way to catch the errors.

```
function getPositionalTrack()
{
    $url = "https://...";

    $result = file_get_contents($url);
    if (false === $result) {
        return null;
    }

    $obj = json_decode($result, true);
    if (null === $obj) {
        return null;
    }

    if (isset($obj['lat']) && isset($obj['lon'])) {
        return $obj;
    }

    return null;
}

$track = getPositionalTrack();
if (null !== $track) {
    $lat = $track['lat'];
    $lon = $track['lon'];
}
```

Or throw exceptions by your own in the function:

```
function getPositionalTrack()
{
    $url = "https://...";

    $result = file_get_contents($url);
    if (false === $result) {
        throw new Exception('file_get_contents failed');
    }

    $obj = json_decode($result, true);
    if (null === $obj) {
        throw new Exception('json_decode failed');
    }

    if (isset($obj['lat']) && isset($obj['lon'])) {
        return $obj;
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception('no lat/lon keys');
    }

}

try {
    $track = getPositionalTrack();
    $lat = $track['lat'];
    $lon = $track['lon'];
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    // react on failure
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way it fails, track is an empty array, so $track[0] will "fail" as you said.

You can try something like this :

```
catch (Exception $e)
{
    $track[0] = //something
    $track[1] = //something else
}
```

Or handle it outside after your function call, but it would be messy

Comment: If you're going to `die` immediately afterwards anyway, what's the point...? :P

Comment: @deceze Yeah my bad, just pasted OP code and forgot to remove it, thanks. Edited this